# keras: cnn+lstm model using time distributed layer runtime error

Tags: keras, deep-learning, python-3.5, lstm, conv-neural-network

I am using cnn with lstm model using time distributed layer for image classification. Although I have compiled the model, still it shows

```
RuntimeError: You must compile your model before using it.
```

I searched on multiple sites but I cannot find solution to my problem.
Here is my code:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Convolution2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers import TimeDistributed
from keras.layers import LSTM

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

# Initialising the CNN
classifier = Sequential()

# Step 1 - Convolution
classifier.add(TimeDistributed(Convolution2D(32, (3, 3), padding = 'same', input_shape = (128, 128, 3), 
                                             activation = 'relu')))

# Step 2 - 
classifier.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2))))

# Adding a second convolutional layer
classifier.add(TimeDistributed(Convolution2D(64, (3, 3), padding = 'same', activation = 'relu')))
classifier.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2))))

# Adding a third conolutional layer
classifier.add(TimeDistributed(Convolution2D(64, (3, 3), padding = 'same', activation = 'relu')))
classifier.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2))))

# Step 3 - Flattening
classifier.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
classifier.add(Dropout(rate = 0.5))

# Step 4 - Full connection
classifier.add(LSTM(256, return_sequences=False, dropout=0.5))
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 8, activation = 'softmax'))

# Compiling the CNN
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

# Part 2 - Fitting the CNN to the images

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   height_shift_range =  0.1,
                                   width_shift_range = 0.1,
                                   channel_shift_range = 10)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/mel/train/',
                                                 target_size = (128, 128),
                                                 batch_size = 32,
                                                 class_mode = 'categorical')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/mel/test/',
                                            target_size = (128, 128),
                                            batch_size = 32,
                                            class_mode = 'categorical')

classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
                         samples_per_epoch = 1088,
                         nb_epoch = 1,
                         validation_data = test_set,
                         nb_val_samples = 352)
```

Here is the complete output message:

```
Found 1088 images belonging to 8 classes.
Found 352 images belonging to 8 classes.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-6a3839aea8f8> in <module>()
     81                          nb_epoch = 1,
     82                          validation_data = test_set,
---> 83                          nb_val_samples = 352)

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     89                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name +
     90                               '` call to the Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
---> 91             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     92         wrapper._original_function = func
     93         return wrapper

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit_generator(self, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
   1424             use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing,
   1425             shuffle=shuffle,
-> 1426             initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
   1427 
   1428     @interfaces.legacy_generator_methods_support

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training_generator.py in fit_generator(model, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
     35 
     36     do_validation = bool(validation_data)
---> 37     model._make_train_function()
     38     if do_validation:
     39         model._make_test_function()

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in _make_train_function(self)
    482     def _make_train_function(self):
    483         if not hasattr(self, 'train_function'):
--> 484             raise RuntimeError('You must compile your model before using it.')
    485         self._check_trainable_weights_consistency()
    486         if self.train_function is None:

RuntimeError: You must compile your model before using it.
```

What can be the possible mistakes.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to use TimeDistributed as an input layer, you have to specify input_shape in TimeDistributed constructor, not Convolution one (or any layer you want to distribute). Keep in mind that you have to provide number of timesteps (frames) in this constructor. In your case it would look like that:

```
num_frames = 10 # e.g.
# Step 1 - Convolution
classifier.add(TimeDistributed(Convolution2D(32, (3, 3), padding = 'same', activation = 
'relu'), input_shape = (num_frames,128, 128, 3)))
```